# Too often it fails to connect to the database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, innodb, myisam

I have a VPS with 2 CPU Cores, 2 GB RAM, 40 GB SSD RAID 10 and 6 websites which often fail to connect to MySQL.
2 of them use InnoDB engine and others with MyISAM.

**the most common error is**

- Unable to connect to database (for 2 website that working with displaying data from database)
- Error establishing a database connection
- Warning: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away...
- Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=5319 in...
- Parse error - syntax error, unexpected...

**What's in the my.cnf file is**

```
#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

[mysqld]

default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err
performance-schema=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
wait_timeout=100
default-storage-engine = MyISAM
max_connections=150
max_allowed_packet=512M
open_files_limit=10000

key_buffer_size=1024M
sort_buffer_size = 10M
read_buffer_size = 12M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 24M
max_heap_table_size=128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
myisam_max_sort_file_size=512M
```

Is there anything I need to add or delete so that the database performance gets better?

I also added this before, but my database doesn't work, so I deleted it from the my.cnf file and my database is working again.

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:32M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768M
innodb_log_file_size = 192M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 32M

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer = 5M
write_buffer = 8M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer = 5M
write_buffer = 5M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

**I also use MySQLTuner to get recommendations, but I still don't understand**

```
# ./mysqltuner.pl
>>  MySQLTuner 1.7.15 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
>>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
>>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.2.23-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err(56M)
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err exists
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err is not empty
[!!] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err is bigger than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err contains 313374 warning(s).
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err contains 35791 error(s).
[--] 830 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err
[--] 1) 2019-04-01 22:08:39 139841626527936 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2019-04-01 22:04:37 140567868758208 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2019-04-01 22:01:32 140443240147136 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2019-04-01 21:54:21 139779152431296 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2019-04-01 21:49:33 140472383613120 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2019-04-01 21:44:08 140427658705088 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 2019-04-01 21:38:45 140701406279872 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 2019-04-01 21:33:54 140239763036352 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 9) 2019-04-01 21:31:26 140259203938496 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 10) 2019-04-01 21:27:28 140651149260992 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 41 shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err
[--] 1) 2019-04-01 16:09:56 139685222135552 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2019-04-01 15:57:02 139843330197248 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2019-04-01 14:41:29 140713465878272 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 2019-04-01  8:44:31 139676564809472 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 2019-04-01  7:05:31 140518647924480 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 2019-04-01  6:49:08 139777831921408 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 2019-04-01  5:02:09 140472744417024 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 8) 2019-04-01  4:18:17 140251689785088 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 9) 2019-04-01  2:09:03 140633617929984 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 10) 2019-04-01  2:07:31 140302801114880 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 85.1M (Tables: 473)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 3.5M (Tables: 17)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 6)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 618 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 4m 58s (9K q [33.138 qps], 438 conn, TX: 138M, RX: 2M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 1.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 8.1G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 1.3G global + 46.5M per thread (150 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.5G (84.10% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 8.1G (451.22% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/9K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 3% (5/150)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/438)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 8K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (14 temp sorts / 2K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 83% (1K on disk / 1K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (5 created / 438 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 86% (80 open / 92 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (147/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (13K immediate / 13K locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 2 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.2.23-MariaDB)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 38.9% (417M used / 1B cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 1.0G/12.1M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.6% (859K cached / 3K reads)
[OK] Write Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (74 cached / 74 writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/3.5M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75 %): 48.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.69% (143198 hits/ 143648 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 0% (3 hits/ 0 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 3 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 99.8% (445K cached / 1K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
/var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err is > 32Mb, you should analyze why or implement a rotation log strategy such as logrotate!
Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err file
Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err file
MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys for MySQL
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/good-dba/mariadb-sys for MariaDB
Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit,ly/2TcGgtU
Variables to adjust:
*** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
*** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
query_cache_size (=0)
query_cache_type (=0)
query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
tmp_table_size (> 16M)
max_heap_table_size (> 128M)
performance_schema = ON enable PFS
innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

================================

## ## UPDATE ##

I updated mysql my.cnf file. but still often get database errors. the database is not really down, only when I will execute something like updating a post, or saving settings in wordpress I get an error

**Warning**: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in **/home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/db.php on line 1767**

**Warning**: mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in **/home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/db.php on line 1767**

**Error reconnecting to the database**

---

My new **# cat /etc/my.cnf**

```
#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

[mysqld]

default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err
performance-schema=ON
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_log_file_size=16M
wait_timeout=100
default-storage-engine = MyISAM
max_connections=12
max_allowed_packet=512M
open_files_limit=10000

key_buffer_size=512M
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 24M
max_heap_table_size=1024M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 48M
myisam_max_sort_file_size=96M
skip-name-resolve=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_limit=1M
tmp_table_size=256M
```

---

**# ./mysqltuner.pl**

```
>>  MySQLTuner 1.7.15 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
>>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
>>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.2.23-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err(59M)
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err exists
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err is not empty
[!!] Log file /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err is bigger than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err contains 330810 warning(s).
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err contains 39811 error(s).
[--] 1028 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err
[--] 1) 2019-04-02 17:19:32 140451092080832 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2019-04-02 17:15:59 139781391579328 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2019-04-02 17:10:00 140566747175104 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2019-04-02 17:04:24 139905996675264 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2019-04-02 17:01:59 140564021029056 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2019-04-02 16:48:20 140572311222464 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 2019-04-02 16:47:09 139981523740864 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 2019-04-02 16:29:05 140624985798848 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 9) 2019-04-02 16:25:39 140484112480448 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 10) 2019-04-02 16:24:23 140350801832128 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 53 shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err
[--] 1) 2019-04-02  3:51:32 140480395822848 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2019-04-02  3:48:12 140626773993216 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2019-04-02  3:25:21 140423948707584 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 2019-04-02  3:23:05 139939032147712 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 2019-04-02  3:12:08 139665156949760 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 2019-04-02  3:04:25 140500729034496 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 2019-04-02  2:43:18 139872808572672 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 8) 2019-04-02  2:33:35 139946881767168 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 9) 2019-04-02  0:35:29 139707099289344 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 10) 2019-04-02  0:32:17 139934613985024 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 87.3M (Tables: 473)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 3.5M (Tables: 18)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 6)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 618 basic passwords in the list.

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1m 43s (1K q [12.971 qps], 25 conn, TX: 14M, RX: 535K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 97% / 3%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 1.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 1.4G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 1.0G global + 27.3M per thread (12 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 76M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.1G (63.70% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.4G (78.54% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/1K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 16% (2/12)
[!!] Aborted connections: 4.00%  (1/25)
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (2 temp sorts / 291 sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 76% (103 on disk / 134 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 92% (2 created / 25 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 91% (157 open / 172 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 2% (298/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (1K immediate / 1K locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 76.1M
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 2 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.2.23-MariaDB)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.6% (99M used / 536M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 512.0M/12.2M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 98.1% (113K cached / 2K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 83.3% (90 cached / 75 writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/3.5M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 16.0M * 2/128.0M should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[!!] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 79.96% (1895 hits/ 2370 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 0% (3 hits/ 0 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 3 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 99.8% (42K cached / 97 reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
/var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err is > 32Mb, you should analyze why or implement a rotation log strategy such as logrotate!
Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err file
Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/server1.nctest.net.err file
MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Reduce or eliminate unclosed connections and network issues
Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys for MySQL
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/good-dba/mariadb-sys for MariaDB
```

How I solve it.

Comment: To back up a bit, and possibly cover ground you've already gone over: when it says it can't connect to the db, is the db truly down? (or perhaps it's up but having problems connecting.) The main purpose of asking is to try to be sure it's performance problems and not something else. Closely related: have you looked at the database error logs?

Comment: Did you try to apply the recommendation from MySQL Tuner? look at this info lines  ```*** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
*** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***``` Probably your MySQL server gives "gone away" because of high load ram usage.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: When you have max_connections=12 there will be connection failures when 12 are in use.  Suggestion, max_connections=151 for the default, Thread_cache_size=64 for thread breathing room.  Read_rnd_buffer_size=256K from 24M to conserve RAM per connection requested to reduce MySQL footprint.

Comment: Hi @WilsonHauck thanks for your suggestion, I have applied it to my.cnf file. set max_connections=151 Thread_cache_size=64 and Read_rnd_buffer_size=256K. I will be back

Comment: @DigitalFun Are you past your connection failures?

Comment: @DigitalFun Additional CURRENT information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have to look at the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html (shall apply if your MySQL version < 8.0) and gather some hints here. This seemed to be some sort of a timeout issue or a network issue that cause the connection to terminate. You can check if there's some kind of firewall that is limiting the packets being sent or increase your timeout variables. For example, your wait_timeout is set to 100 seconds only probably your query runs longer than that, though that could mean a bad query for 100 sec unless it's pulling a large/long list of records that is supposed to be executed seldom. Take a look at how the default variables for *_timeout in the MySQL documentation and try to tune it if it's lower than its default value.

Answer (score 1):

With only 1.8GB of RAM, several settings are dangerously high:

```
max_allowed_packet=512M  -- 50M
open_files_limit=10000   -- 1000
key_buffer_size=1024M    -- 100M
max_heap_table_size=128M        -- 50M
max_heap_table_size=1024M   -- really bad!
max_connections=12       -- better
sort_buffer_size = 1M    -- better
read_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 1M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 48M  -- better
myisam_max_sort_file_size=96M
tmp_table_size=256M     -- 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768M   -- 100M
```

The server seemed to be restarting rapidly after over-allocating memory.